# Twilio Conversations - Scoped Conversations and Messaging Services - how to connect?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations

I'm trying to make sure a phone number attached to a Messaging Service auto create a conversation in a specific conversation service *not* the default one. From the Conversations > Default screen on the console I can read this:

[image]

What steps do I have to follow here to "specify another Messaging Service" in my request when the conversations are being auto created by twilio?

Requirements are:

- I need a specific phone number creating a conversation in a specific Conversation Service as these are scoped to individual customers.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I don't know this one, so I'm checking with the team. Hope to have an answer for you soon.

Comment: Hi @philnash - thanks for you help. Support got back to me suggested change the Conversation messaging service after it's been created rather than auto creating in the correct conversation service :(

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently it is not possible to choose the conversation service for a messaging service to autocreate conversations in. The default conversation service is the only one that will be used to autocreate conversations.

An alternative approach here would be to [create a new subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/subaccounts) for each of your individual customers. You can then host your numbers, messaging service and conversation service for that customer within the subaccount and handle this use-case.